# how to add dynamic columns in gridview and insert values in column? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is 'gridview1' and i want this type of output in gridview [image]

Where as columns names get from sql query .When user insert values in textbox and press button then values insert and next row initialize and again insert values etc.I'm beginner and i don't know how to do this.
Here is my aspx.cs code :

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     load();
  }
}
public void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string tbl_name = Session["value"].ToString();
   string query = "USE Student SELECT column_name,data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + tbl_name + "'";
   SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,cnn);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   cnn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   da.Fill(dt);
   cnn.Close();
if (dt != null)
  {
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {        
 }
}
```